# How to make a HWIOAuthBundle RegistrationFormHandler without FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony

I want to let users register with ***[HWIOAuthBundle](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle)*** (for example with Facebook).
I have my custom UserBundle instead of FosUserBundle.

**I want to accomplish that if a user presses the Facebook button on the registration-page that the username and email appear in the registration form and let the user fill in the rest of the registration form.**

emphasized textSo far as i can see i need to Use a `RegistrationFormHandler` that implements `RegistrationFormHandlerInterface` from the HWIOAuthBundle. and that i have to add two services in the configuration:

```
connect:
    confirmation: true
    account_connector: my_user_provider
    registration_form_handler: app.registration.form.handler
    registration_form: app.form.register
```

The problem i have is that i dont know how to write the service definition for ***app.form.register*** service since this must in fact be the [Symfony\Component\Form\Form](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.html) class which is a configured form.

I should have something like this i think:

```
   app.form.register:
        class: Symfony\Component\Form\Form
        arguments: [@FormConfigInterface]
```

But the [FormConfigInterface](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/Form/FormConfigInterface.html) must be filled with the formType and formData and so on...